# Magento 1.9.0.1 - Category URL Rewrites - Cannot intitialize the indexer process

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing, reindex, mysql-indexes

I finally got my local installation of Magento 1.9.0.1 with the sample data up and running - XAMPP 1.8.3 on Windows 7 (Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.15).  Everything was working fine with all the status warning cleared until I tried to add a Website (System -> Manage Stores -> Create Website).  I was able to create the website, and also create a store and store view under that website, but then I ran into trouble.  The following message appeared: "One or more of the Indexes are not up to date: Catalog URL Rewrites. Click here to go to Index Management and rebuild required indexes."

I tried clearing all caches, and reindexing the data, but I continued to get the message.  I then tried deleting the new website, store and store view that I had created, but am still getting the message.  It's the Category URL Rewrites that's causing the problem.

Any help on how to resolve this is greatly appreciated.